How to write to stdin of another process in C on Linux?
I have one command (cmd_c) which can get input from STDIN and process the input data.
I want to call this command in a process A, and process A will provide data to the cmd_c.
The process A called fork() + execv() to start a child process to run command of cmd_c, but I did NOT find the right way to send data from process A to cmd_c?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int pid;

    /* continued */
    if ((pid = fork()) > 0) {
///     does something else
///     How to send data to child process's STDIN???
        wait(NULL);
    } else {
        char *arg_list[] = {"./cmd_c", NULL};
        int rc = execv("./cmd_c", arg_list);
        printf("Child execv = %d\n", rc);
    }
    return 0;
}

The cmd_c.c is as follows,
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char buf[256];
        while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, stdin)) {
              printf("XXXXXXXXX %s\n", buf);
        }
        return 0;
}


Are you looking for popen(3)?

@ChrisDavies I used popen in other cases, but I don't know how to use popen in this case to deliver data from one process to another process's STDIN.

this is all pure C; I'd honestly remove the C++ from the question title, since it is a bit surprising. Your first program is not valid C++ (because casting from a const char* string literal to char* discards the constness, and literals in C++ are constants.

also, for wait() you need to include <sys/wait.h>, even in C.

Create a pipe and the two fds connected to the read and write ends with pipe(), juggle them to the correct places in the child (and parent if needed) with dup2(), and then read and write using the fds. If you're going to exec() another program, you need to move the read end to the stdin fd (0) in the child, but the parent can keep its own stdout separate from the pipe write fd if it runs your code.
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    /* [0] = read end, [1] = write end */
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        /* child, move the read end to stdin and close the orig pipe fds */
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execlp("sed", "sed", "s/.*/sed((&))/", (char *) NULL);
    } else {
        /* parent, close the read end */
        close(pipefd[0]);
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, "hello\n", 6);  /* directly to stdout */
        write(pipefd[1], "world\n", 6); /* written to the pipe */
        /* close the write end when done, so the child exits */
        close(pipefd[1]);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}

The output should be:
hello
sed((world))

(But note that writes through the pipe and child will be slower to reach the terminal (or where ever stdout is connected), so you may get some reordering of the output. Doesn't matter if you don't write directly to stdout from the parent.)

Thanks for answering the question, it worked for me.  And I would only use write to send data from parent to child's stdin through PIPE, is there any risk to hit the data reordering?

@wangt13 — Since you're simply writing to the child, and no other process is doing that, there is no risk of the data being reordered.  If you need to read data produced by the child process (as well as writing to it), life is more difficult in the general case.  If the responses are small and written all at once, you can handle it simply.  If the responses are big (> 64 KiB) or written piecemeal, life is a lot more difficult unless the child process unambiguously marks the end of each response (either by a size at the start or a marker at the end).

The child process is doing some data processing, and may reply some status codes or percentage to the parent, the data size should NOT be large than 4KB-8KB, I think.
